# How to extract substrings with PHP

Tags: php, string

PHP beginner's question.

I need to keep image paths as following in the database for the admin backend.

```
../../../../assets/images/subfolder/myimage.jpg
```

However I need image paths as follows for the front-end.

```
assets/images/subfolder/myimage.jpg
```

What is the best way to change this by PHP?

I thought about substr(), but I am wondering if there is better ways.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the directory structure? What will turn `../../../../assets` into `assets` ? What are your root and base directories? Or are you simply looking for making a replacement of those exact values? For that, there's str_replace(): http://www.php.net/str_replace otherwise, I think we need more info.

Comment: Why do you need to have different paths for the backend and the frontend? Why don’t you use just one path and adjust it with a prefix?

Answer (score 0):

you should save your image path in an **application variable** and can access from both admin and frontend

Answer (score 0):

If ../../../../ is fixed, then substr will work. If not, try something like this:

```
newpath=substr(strpos(path, "assets"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It might seem like an odd choice at first but you could use [ltrim](http://at.php.net/ltrim). In the following example, all `../`'s will be removed from the beginning of `$path`.
The dots in the second argument have to be escaped because PHP would treat them as a range otherwise.

```
$path = ltrim('../../../../assets/images/subfolder/myimage.jpg', '\\.\\./');
```

`$path` will then be:

```
assets/images/subfolder/myimage.jpg
```

Comment: Note that the second parameter of `ltrim` denotes a *list* of characters that ought to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this

```
$path = "../../../../assets/images/subfolder/myimage.jpg";
$root = "../../../../";

$root_len = strlen($root);

if(substr($path, 0, $root_len) == $root){
    echo substr($path, $root_len);
} else {
    //not comparable
}
```

In this way you have a sort of control on which directory to consider as root for your images